# Add Percentage symbol in SSRS column's expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a column in which for all the values of column I need the percentage symbol in the end. So what should I put in the expression for this.
Like currently I have in the expression ->

```
=Fields!Contribution_Margin_.Value
```

To get this '%' symbol in the end what should I do? All the calculations I have done at the backend so only the symbol is required.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a decimal number that represents the percentage you can just use the `format` function to format the number:

```
=format(Fields!Contribution_Margin_.Value,"0%")
```

Or if you want to keep the value as a number within the report, you can set the `Format` number property of wherever it is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the number is stored.

Let's say you have a value that needs to be shown as `12.5%`

If the value stored in your dataset is actually `0.125` (this is the correct way) then all you need to do is set the format property of the textbox to `p1`. The means "format as percentage to 1 decimal place"

If your dataset value is actually `12.5` then you can set the format property to something like

`0.0 "%"` to show to 1 decimal place or

`0.00 "%"` to show to two decimal places etc.

Alternatively you could just divide the value by 100 to get back to a "proper" percentage value and use the standard formatting codes as shown in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to add % symbol; just add the % symbol in the same textbox as your placeholder, not in your expression.

[image]